# Spring DefaultJmsListenerContainer tuning for listening to multiple queues

Tags: spring, spring-boot, amazon-sqs, spring-jms

we have 50 @JMSListener classes connecting to 50 different SQS Queues from same application.
is it better to use the different listener containers for each queue.

We are using the same ListenerContainer with SQSConnectionFactory for sending and receiving the messages.
Will it help in performance if we add separate ListenerContainer for queues and 
multiple JMSTemplates to to send messages to queues with high number of messages.
my configs are as follows.

```
    public void sqsContainerFactory(){
        connectionFactory = new SQSConnectionFactory(
                new ProviderConfiguration(),
                AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard()
                        .withRegion(region)
                        .withCredentials(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain())
                );      
    }

    //Used in all Listeners as containerFactory
   @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> sqsFactory() {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(this.connectionFactory);
        factory.setDestinationResolver(new DynamicDestinationResolver());
        factory.setConcurrency("1-25");
        factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        return factory;
    }
   //Used to send messages to SQS 
    @Bean("SQS")
    @Primary
    public JmsTemplate defaultJmsTemplate() {
        return new JmsTemplate(this.connectionFactory);
    }
```

could you please advise

Answer (score 0):

If you have 50 `@JMSListener` classes listening on 50 queues, then you already have 50 ListenerContainers.  I don't know of any way to have a `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` listen on more than one queue.

If you are having performance issues, look at the `org.messaginghub.pooled.jms.JmsPoolConnectionFactory` or the `org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory`.  By default, the `JMSTemplate` will create a new JMS connection and session for every message sent.  This is very expensive.  Depending on your configuration, the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` can also do this for every message received.

Comment: Thank you Doug. in my config i  have defined DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory with concurrency of 1-25 and used that same factory for all 50 Listeners. Now i am using SQSConnectionfactory directly. will using CachingConnectionFactory help here soemhow.

Comment: As for concurrency, this is the number of session listeners.  I always recommend having this as like 5-5.  Min and max are the same .  Just keep them nailed up.  The pooled connection factory is for performance.  Do not drop the JMS connection and session.  Dropping the JMS  connection is a real performance hit.

Comment: Thank you will make the changes accordingly and try it out  to see improvements. The issue we see is that it takes time to pick message  or acknowledge, we do not see any queue depth but there is a delay before it starts processing after acknowledging the message.